# Serialize array of simple types into a single database field

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to configure NHibernate (specifically Fluent NHibernate) to serialize an array of simple types to a single database column? I seem to remember that this was possible but its been a while since I've used NHibernate.

Essentially I need to store the days of week that a person works (`int[]`) and would rather not have a separate table just for this purpose.

Comment: Have you tried to map a simple array of ints?  The behavior may be dependant on your database, but with SQLite at least, I believe FNH will map it as a BLOB.

Comment: BTW, my previous comment applies to FNH automapping.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You need to implement a `IUserType` that takes care of mapping between your array and a data column (google that first; it's possible that somebody already implemented it)

Alternatively, you can do the conversion in your entity class, and map the single-field representation instead of the property. For example:

```
string numbers;

public int[] Numbers
{
    get { return numbers.Split(','); }
    set { numbers = string.Join(",", value.Select(x => x.ToString())); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's `UserType` for scenarios like that. You could also use enum and `bit flag`.